# UITabBarItems doesn't appears

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I created a TabBarController but their TabBarItems doesn't appears.

What am I doing wrong? Because Ive already added the tabBarItem of View Controllers, and they don't appears.

```
//Create Controllers
SBQNewsViewController *news=[[SBQNewsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
SBQFavoritesViewController *favs=[[SBQFavoritesViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

//Create NavigationControllers
UINavigationController *newsNav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:news];
UINavigationController *favsNav=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favs];

//Create TabBarController
UITabBarController *tabReader=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabReader.viewControllers=@[newsNav,favsNav];

self.window.rootViewController=tabReader;
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

[image: Screen]

And the tabBarItems added:

Into SBQNewsViewController:

```
#import "SBQNewsViewController.h"

   @implementation SBQNewsViewController

   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
   {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Reportslc.png"];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Noticias";
    }
    return self;
   }
```

Into SBQFavoritesViewController:

```
#import "SBQFavoritesViewController.h"

  @interface SBQFavoritesViewController ()

  @end

  static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIdentifier";

  @implementation SBQFavoritesViewController

  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
  {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Favoritelc.png"];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Favoritos";
    }
    return self;
  }
```

Comment: Your TabBarcontoller is there on your screen. Try to set tabBarItem.title for each controller and test it.

Comment: I set both tabBarItem: self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Reportslc.png"];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Noticias";

Comment: And:  self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Favoritelc.png"];
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Favoritos";

Comment: In both Controllers. I dont understand why the tabBarItem doesn't appears

Comment: Read this link It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894985/uitabbar-not-showing-selected-item-images-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

You have not added tabBarItem title to your code.. USe tabBarItem.title and set some title to see your tab bars..

Comment: Ive already added. Thats because I dont understand why doesnt appears

Answer (score 0):

I set the Items into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and it works now

```
UITabBarItem *itemsNews=[tabReader.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    [itemsNews setTitle:@"Noticias"];

UITabBarItem *itemsFavs=[tabReader.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    [itemsFavs setTitle:@"Favoritos"];
```

Thanks Bhumeshwer katre!

Comment: Better use this  in iOS 7 only   `[itemsNews setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unselected.png"]];`

Comment: Ok, Im going to change it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting the tabBarItem.title try setting the screentitle:

```
self.title = @"Favoritos";
```