# Change non selected items color of UITabBar in iOS7

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm using this code to change `UITabBar` color, its text color/font and the color of the selected item.

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.0f],
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]
                                                        } forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:10.0f],
                                                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                        } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //change tabbarcolor
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    //to change the tabbar elements color
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

My problem is I want to change the color of the NON SELECTED `UITabBarItem`s, that are in grey color per default. How can I do that ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution (that it's a bit longer) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894985/uitabbar-not-showing-selected-item-images-in-ios-7):

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[[self window] rootViewController];

UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];

tabBarItem1.title = @"Home";
tabBarItem2.title = @"Map";
tabBarItem3.title = @"Weather";
tabBarItem4.title = @"Info";

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
    [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_home_white.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_home_black.png"]];
    [tabBarItem2 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_cloud_white.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_cloud_black.png"]];
    [tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_map_white.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_map_black.png"]];
    [tabBarItem4 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_info_white.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_info_black.png"]];
} else {
    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_home_white"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_home_black"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_cloud_white"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_cloud_black"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem3.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_map_white"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_map_black"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];

    tabBarItem4.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_info_white"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
    tabBarItem4.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"cyexplore_info_black"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
}

UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected.png"]];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```