# How to change color of inactive tab-bar icons in ios7?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I'd like to change the color of inactive icons in the tab bar in ios7.

I know how to set the color to selected TabBar item, But I don't know how to set the color to inactive TabBar items.

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks in advance!!

This is my code in appDelegate.m

```
//tint color for tabbar
[UITabBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.077 green:0.411 blue:0.672 alpha:1.000];

//tint color for the text of inactive tabbar item.
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:        [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//tint color for the text of selected tabbar item.
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:        [UIColor orangeColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];

//tint color for the selected tabbar item.
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

//tint color for the inactive tabbar items.
//Question:how can I set tint color for the inactive tabbar items???
```

Comment: I believe that the tab bar's tint color is the color of inactive tabs, because there is also a `selectedImageTintColor`. I am not 100% sure about this though without actual testing.

Comment: @foriinrangeawesome You are incorrect. Apple really screwed this up. The `selectedImageTintColor` is ignored and the inactive tabs are always gray with no API to change it.

Comment: Apple should really revise its documentation

Comment: Though there seems to be a workaround. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894985/uitabbar-not-showing-selected-item-images-in-ios-7

Comment: @maddy really!!!?? there is no way to change it!? that's too bad...

Answer (score 13):

It's true that there no easy way to do change the colour of inactive image. It does not seem to be possible to do within a storyboard at all. There's a pretty straightforward solution though — just assign the item an image with `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` rendering mode.

Given that your images are already coloured for inactive state originally, you can create a simple custom subclass of `UITabBarItem` with the following implementation

```
@implementation P2TabBarItem

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setImage:self.image]; // calls setter below to adjust image from storyboard / nib file
}

- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [super setImage:[image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    self.selectedImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
}

@end
```

In your storyboard, fill the Class field of all your UITabBarItems to the newly created subclass name — that's it!

Comment: I'm not even surprised that you can't simply define an inactive tint color, it's Apple after all...

Answer (score 1):

Apple discourages of changing a tint of active item only because color blind users will have a hard time distinguishing which tab bar item is active.

Having said that, even if you still want different color inactive item icons, you should initialise your `tabBarItem` property in view controller's initialiser with images that are returned from `imageWithRenderingMode:` method.

Something like

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        UIImage * tabImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"InactiveImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage * selectedTabImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ActiveImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Item", @"Tab bar button title for 'Item'")
                                                        image:tabImage
                                                selectedImage:selectedTabImage];
    };
    return self;
}
```

This way item will switch between your provided icons without adding a tint on them. The text though will still switch the tint color that you provided through either IB or `appearance` proxy in code.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your UITabBarController

```
UITabBarItem *item0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
//unselected icon
item0.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_icon.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
//selected icon
item0.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_icon.png"];
```