# How can I get the ViewController icon in XCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/), however my TableView has absolutely no icons under it, so I'm not sure how to connect the data array from the ViewController.m to the Table View. Every tutorial I've come across has the icons, though I am using Xcode 6.0

Comment: Are you talking about the tiny icons you see at bottom (under the view comtroller)?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are doing?

Comment: The icons are at the top in Xcode 6. IF you select the scene, they should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the `initWithTitle:image:tag:` ? Maybe the image you selected is not available.

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = 
  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TWO"
                                image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GT_TWO.png" 
                                  tag:0];
self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
```

[Here is also an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20110034/1141395) where everything is setup in one plays, maybe nice if you have a subclass of `UITabBarController`. But you could also set it up inside the UIViewController which should be represented by a tap.

Comment: @Chuckie do you think it makes it more easy to read a post if you have to scroll inside the code box?