# Setting navigation bar item image in storyboard does not work

Tags: ios, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a navigation bar item through storyboard with custom image and it does not work.

This is the result:

[image]

The image I'm using is not a blue circle, here is the settings and object structure:

[image]

[image]

The image has the appropriate size and I have tried with multiple images all with the same result.

Comment: Does your png file have an alpha channel?  Sometimes the icon just gets colored in if not.

Comment: For educational purposes, how do you know that?

Comment: I used a png without alpha once on a tab bar item and all that appeared was a colored icon just like yours.  Changed the alpha and it worked.  The tint color sort of took over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because navigation bar treats it's images as templates and will display them by applying standard Tint Color.

To display an image in it's original form you need to use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` as rendering mode of the image.

You can set this in `viewDidLoad` method of your `UIViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIBarButtonItem* rightButton = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;
    [rightButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner way to do this using  xcassets http://stackoverflow.com/a/33254730/884674