# Difficulty to get to TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, icons, uitabbarcontroller

There is something with my ViewControllers' hierarchy that I don't get. Please take a look at my Storyboard:

[image]

What I'm trying to do, is programmatically setting the TabBarItem image associated with the NavigationController in the center of the Bottom Row.
I want to do that with a button on the ViewController at Bottom Right.

I tried several things, like

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.image = someValidImage;
```

and

```
UITabBarItem *myIcon =[self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
    myIcon.image = someValidImage;
```

but to no avail.

I'm sure it is something obvious, but I'm staring at this quite a while now. 
Could any of you help me out here?

Comment: did you try "self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ItemX"];
" ?

Comment: Actually, I didn't! And it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this here we set two types of image one for selected-state other one for unselected state
hope this will help you!!..

here "xyz" will be your image name.

```
[[tabBarController_obj.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] tabBarItem]setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"]];
```

try this for all tabs in ur case , I think u have to do three time.

Comment: Oh..my..dear..god! That must be the problem. Thank you so much! Let me try. I will reward you.

Comment: That was it; your recommendation put an end to hours of misery. There is a more detailed (and less deprecated) explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894985/uitabbar-not-showing-selected-item-images-in-ios-7